# How to use Pandas group-by and sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

this is my dataframe:

```
    RefactoringType      Detail
0   Move Method         com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
1   Move Source Folder  NaN
2   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
3   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
4   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
5   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
6   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
7   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
8   Move Attribute      com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
9   Rename Method       com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog
```

the column Detail contain the name of classes.I need to calculate the number of RefactoringType in each class.
I tried this:

```
g1 = df1.groupby(["Detail", "RefactoringType"]).sum()
```

It return for me:

```
Detail                                         RefactoringType
com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog    Move Attribute
                                                Move Method
                                                Rename Method
```

I need the result like this:

```
 Class                                       Move Method   Move Attribute Rename Method

com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog  1             1                    1
```

PS: after I will define all the type of refactoring.
Thanks for help

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.Detail, df.RefactoringType)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['Detail', 'RefactoringType']).size()\
    .unstack().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

For the following test DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 'Move Attribute', 'ColorPickerDialog' ],
    [ 'Move Method',    'ColorPickerDialog' ],
    [ 'Rename Method',  'ColorPickerDialog' ],
    [ 'Rename Method',  'ColorPickerDialog' ],
    [ 'Rename Method',  'XxxxxxxxxxxDialog' ],
    [ 'Rename Method',  'XxxxxxxxxxxDialog' ]],
    columns=['RefactoringType', 'Detail'])
```

I got:

```
RefactoringType    Move Attribute  Move Method  Rename Method
Detail                                                       
ColorPickerDialog               1            1              2
XxxxxxxxxxxDialog               0            0              2
```